# Certain probabilistic measure on $\kappa$ implies it has the tree property?

Tags: set-theory

$\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal on which there is a countably additive probabilistic measure $m$ that vanishes on singletons and the ideal of sets of $m$-measure $0$ is $\kappa$-complete.

The problem in question is to prove that every $\kappa$-tree has a branch of length $\kappa$.

I don't event know what to think of this problem. I see absolutetly no connection between the assumptions and the statement. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: Think about the tree order as $(\kappa, \prec)$, and each stage as you build a path you have to choose the ``majority'', aka the set of nodes lying above a current node has large measure.

Comment: As you see from the argument suggested in the comment above, you forgot an important assumption, namely that all subsets of $\kappa$ are measurable.

Comment: It seems so. @Jing Zhang Could you elaborate a bit on that, because I still don't follow? How do I know there's always a level above that is large according to measure $m$?

Comment: A measure which is $\kappa$-complete will satisfy that any partition of a set of positive measure into less than $\kappa$ sets will have a part which has positive measure.

Comment: Sorry for not being too bright but I still don't get it :(

Comment: Think about the proof of König's lemma in the countable case. Now replace "inifnite" with "positive measure".

Comment: Yes, I got it, that's brilliant! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Now that this is out of the way, let me point out that my preferred argument is via elementary embeddings. Your assumption implies that in an appropriate forcing extension there is an embedding of the ground model into a transitive model. The embedding "enlarges" the tree so, in the extension, we see branches. One then argues using the measure that we can define the branch in the ground model. The argument is particularly simple when we have a measurable or even a weakly compact cardinal: There is no forcing involved, the embeddings are in the ground model.

Comment: (You can see details in Corollary 3.23 of my thesis or Corollary 1.25 of my paper on real-valued measurable cardinals. Both are available [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/papers/).)

Comment: @Jules: Well you need to be a bit careful at limit stages though, as it is possible that infinite intersection of sets of positive measure is measure 0.

Comment: So a more careful way (therefore with more guaranteed success) is that you first trim the tree to a $\kappa$-subtree such that each level only consists of countably many nodes, then you find a cofinal path in this subtree (it is a theorem of Kurepa I believe). How do you get such a tree? For each level, there are at most countably many nodes that are large (aka, the set of nodes above it has positive measure), these are the nodes you keep for the subtree.

Comment: Smart, but why there can't be uncountably many nodes (on some level) that have something of positive measure above them?

Comment: Because these sets are disjoint, and think about why you can't have uncountably many disjoint sets of positive measure. How many sets that have measure greater than 1/n for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Right. But Kurepa's theorem is true if the levels have cardinality less than $cf(\kappa)$. So what if $\kappa$ is singular and say, has $cf(\kappa)=\omega$?

Comment: It can't be singular, otherwise the whole space is covered by a $<\kappa$ union of null sets, therefore null.

Comment: Indeed, it really seems I'm not very smart. Thanks once again!

Comment: You are welcome ;-)

Comment: Don't belittle yourself. We all start somewhere. Being knowledgeable takes time and tenacity. Experience is nothing more than having a large toolkit and the know-how to apply these tricks in certain situation.